# Retornar a página anterior após o login no facebook oauth

Tags: php, facebook, login, sdk, oauth

Uso o sistema de Login pelo facebook padrão, nele pede pra inserir ***App ID*** o ***App Secret*** e a URL que irá retornar após solicitar o login ao usuário, minha duvida é, como fazer para retornar a url no qual foi solicitado o login. em varias páginas estará o botão de Login, então gostaria que retornasse a página de origem. Como faço?

Comment: Ele abre uma nova janela para fazer a autenticação, nao abre?

Comment: Na verdade abre na mesma janela. solicita autenticação e permissão para login e depois retorna a página de login meusite.com.br/login/

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver gerando o link de login via php é só mudá-lo dinamicamente.

Por exemplo, na página de notícias fica:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://seusite/noticia.php');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
...
```

e nela mesmo pra receber/verificar o usuário de volta fica:

```
if ( !empty($_GET['code']) ){
...
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://seusite/noticia.php');
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch
...
```

* quando o facebook retorna do login ele traz essa variável GET

Obs.: Na verdade esse segundo trecho de código que coloquei deve vir antes do primeiro. Caso tenha $_GET['code'] ( e/ou uma variável de sessão que você vai usar para guardar o token do login) efetua o login, caso não, gera o link de login (o link que vai ter no botão)

Comment: E quando o usuário está em outra pagina tipo "noticias2.php" e ao logar não quer voltar para noticia.php e sim permanecer na noticia2.php